# How can I run ASP.NET Web Application project as a Virtual host , without Visual Studio?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, virtualhost, virtual-hosts

I have an ASP.NET Web Application  that I run from Visual Studio , it uses multiple Nuget packages and SQL Server .

Is it possible to run it **without** Visual Studio , using a virtual host ?

Comment: Do you mean hosting it outside of visual studio? Or do you mean editing/debugging the project outside of visual studio?

Comment: @Pseudonym : No , not debugging . Just running it from some domain that I choose on my computer , without using Visual Studio .

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comments you are looking to begin hosting your own website from your own computer.

1. For starters I would checkout [this](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/older-versions-getting-started/deploying-web-site-projects/asp-net-hosting-options-cs) resource from MSDN
2. A less dense but simpler walkthrough is [here](http://www.developer.com/net/asp/self-hosting-an-asp.net-web-api.html)

It seems like you're not quite sure how to begin researching this yourself, so I would begin looking at search terms like "host ASP.Net site", "self hosting ASP", and "setting up IIS for self hosting"

Another thing you will need to figure out is how to host your databases in SQL server, but running locally you shouldn't encounter any problems. If you're looking to host this online then I would definitely take a look at the services offered by Azure, they integrate so nicely and are a breeze (IMHO) to work with.

Comment: I tried this one `http://www.iisunderground.com/add-a-new-website-iis-7-5/` but I can understand where to put the solution's files . I did a complete setup of all the fields but I keep getting `404 page not found` . Any idea where can I set the path of the solution as the project that I want the IIS to run ? Thanks .

Comment: You don't put the solution files anywhere, you need to take the output from the bin folder and put them in the folder you are pointing IIS to